# SQL/No-SQL agnostic data persistence in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find a gem that provides the ability to persist data to a database in a way that is agnostic of the database that has been configured. For example, I need to support both SQL and "no-SQL" databases. Possibly something that support the repository pattern.

Minimum support should include:

- MySQL
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- MongoDB

I can work on adding support for additional databases, but I'm looking for something that already has a head start on those databases that I listed. It just needs to be able to create, read, update, and delete records in a way that is agnostic of schema/schema-less databases.

Which gem provides this feature?

Comment: There are problems due different presentation of API by SQL vs NoSQL. You will be limited to CRUD operations on single objects, you will have no control over schema (so that has to be done elsewhere and will be dependent on whether backing is SQL vs NoSQL), and have limited or no search/filter capabilities. Efficiencies of either/both SQL/NoSQL for complex queries will be locked out, because they are implemented in the query languages which are not interoperable.

Comment: Having said that, I think your best bet would be gems based around data mapper pattern. These do exist, with `data-mapper` being one of the original ones. However, it is not maintained, and the replacement, `rom` does not look ready yet.

Comment: @NeilSlater Right. I imagine the interface/abstraction would have to "dumb it down" to the most common denominator. It probably wouldn't allow you to take advantage of database specific features.

Comment: as @NeilSlater has covered pretty well already covered any such design would pretty much be a "flying-submarine" (something which has such extreme requirements that it ends up being a worthless). You could instead for example use ActiveRecord and Mongoid in the same app if needed.